# Get version number of iOS Universal Framework in client

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, frameworks, ios-universal-framework

This is likely not limited to [iOS Universal Frameworks](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) but all xxx.framework files. However I can't seem to find documentation on how to get the current version and build of a framework within the client application. Within an app you'd use something like:

```
    NSString *name = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
    NSString *build = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

That would give you the current information stored in the Info.plist for the app. But how to we find that information for a framework. And in my case, specifically an embedded framework.

Comment: Did you manage to get this done?

Comment: No I'm afraid not. However, we're moving from iOS Universal Frameworks to native Xcode 6 Cocoa Touch Frameworks, and maybe we'll have better luck there. I'll update here if I figure it out.

Comment: Thank for confirming

Comment: If its your embedded framework, you can provide some method or property accessible to the client which would point to: [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyFrameworkClass class]] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

Comment: This is how i get my framework bundle -NSBundle *rampBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.example.framework"];

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found that Apple's new Cocoa Touch frameworks supported in Xcode 6, offer an easy answer to this problem. In the default header file created for you, something like `Framework.h`, you'll see two constants declared for you. These are defined later presumably at runtime by internal framework logic. But I have confirmed they're pulled from the plist for the framework.

```
//! Project version number for LocalSearch.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double FrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for LocalSearch.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char FrameworkVersionString[];
```

Comment: I won't mark this as the accepted answer, since most people coming to this page will be looking for an answer for iOS Universal Framework, but as time goes on most will be interested in the new Cocoa Touch frameworks, and here is an answer for them.

Comment: I'm trying this, but despite my framework's info.plist having 3.3 set for both CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString, when I NSLog the 'FrameworkVersionNumber' or 'FrameworkVersionString', I get '1'. Where exactly in the framework's plist are these constants pulling their values?

Comment: @YoCoh As I am aware of, the constants are not pulling the version number from the plist file. Instead, you can set your version by updating `Current Project Version` field under `Versioning` in `Build Settings` of your project. You will notice that, by default, the `Versioning System` is set to Apple Generic. That's how these two constants are updated. However, the string version is not returning just the version number but includes project's and target's name as well. I don't know how you can get rid of that.

Comment: Does anyone know why in Swift, only `var FrameworkVersionNumber: Double` is generated in the module, but there is no variable generated for the `FrameworkVersionString[]`?

Comment: Not sure as to why, but it should be pretty easy to make it presentable with some basic string formatting no?

Comment: Afraid not... `FrameworkVersionNumber` is a double, so it only supports a single decimal, so for example setting a version of 3.2.1 just changes this to the double value "3.2000000". What I need to be able to do is extract the exact version number components, which I believe I'd be able to do with `FrameworkVersionString[]` (if only it was exposed in Swift). Seeing as this is slightly off-topic, I have now posted this as a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418303/get-cocoa-touch-framework-project-version-string-in-swift

Answer (score 26):

Here's a solution that does work with Universal Frameworks. Just replace `SomeFrameworkClass` with a class from the desired framework.

```
if let sdkVersion = Bundle(for: SomeFrameworkClass.self).infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] {
    // sdkVersion is available here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's say `Foo` is a class from the given framework, you can use something like :

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [Foo class]] infoDictionary]; 

NSString *name = [infoDictionary valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];
NSString *version = [infoDictionary valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];

NSLog(@"%@ version %@", name, version);
```

In Swift :

```
// `Foo` is a type defined in the framework
if  let infos = Bundle(for: Foo.self).infoDictionary,
    let name = infos[kCFBundleNameKey as String],
    let version = infos[kCFBundleVersionKey as String] {     
        print("Using \(name) version \(version)")

        if let shortVersion = infos["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            print("Short version : " + shortVersion)
        }
    }
```

Note : For some reason, "CFBundleShortVersionString" is not defined in a constant, cf [Is there a constant defined for CFBundleShortVersionString in iOS/MacOS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187359/is-there-a-constant-defined-for-cfbundleshortversionstring-in-ios-macos-framewor)

Comment: Is it necessary to add `__bridge ` before `NSString`?

Comment: @gabbler I think we need the __bridge because the value is a `CFString`
@NikolayDimitrov `Foo` should be a type from the framework you want the information, you can also try to get the value with the key "CFBundleShortVersionString" (which is not defined in a constant cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187359/is-there-a-constant-defined-for-cfbundleshortversionstring-in-ios-macos-framewor)

Answer (score 0):

This is for who may want to have a function on your framework that returns or print on the console it's version with build number. Just make sure you are using the class you are sharing on your *Framework.h* when declaring the ***infoDictionary**. In my example I'm using a class named *cloud*

```
+(NSString *)frameWorkVersion {
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [cloud class]] infoDictionary];
    NSString *version = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *build = [infoDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
    NSString *fVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",version,build];
    NSLog(@"Framework Version %@",fVersion);

    return fVersion; }
```