# Get Cocoa Touch Framework project version string in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Cocoa Touch Frameworks provide support for versioning, which can be found in **Build Settings** under the **Versioning** section.

To access this value at runtime, we can use the `FrameworkVersionNumber` and `FrameworkVersionString[]` variables which are auto-generated for us as part of the build process.

When working with a Swift project, these can be found auto-generated at the top of the Objective-C compatibility header:

```
//! Project version number for Framework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double FrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for Framework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char FrameworkVersionString[];
```

However, whilst `FrameworkVersionNumber` is accessible from Swift, `FrameworkVersionString[]` is not. In fact looking at the contents of the framework module, I can see that only the first variable is exposed to Swift:

```
//! Project version number for Framework.
var FrameworkVersionNumber: Double
```

The problem with this is that since `FrameworkVersionNumber` is a `Double`, any version numbers like 3.2.1 simply get changed to 3.200000...

Does anyone know whether this is a flaw in my project setup, a bug in Xcode, or whether there is a way of getting the framework version in Swift as a `String` or array, so that I can provide more granular versioning than *major.minor*?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538215/get-version-number-of-ios-universal-framework-in-client

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have actually found a potential workaround for this issue, it's not so clean but it does work:

By default, when Xcode creates a framework it sets the **Version** to `1.0` and the **Build** to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` which is great, because this value is actually being copied from the **Current Project Version** field in Build Settings > Versioning.

So what you can do to get this value at runtime is as follows:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.yourframework.Framework")! // Get a reference to the bundle from your framework (not the bundle of the app itself!)
let build = bundle.infoDictionary![kCFBundleVersionKey] as! String // Get the build from the framework's bundle as a String
```

This does work but it feels quite circuitous for something that used to (I believe) be readily accessible from a variable in Objective-C.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE - OCT 2021 - XCODE 13**

When submitting an app to the App Store, Xcode 13 has a new option called "Manage Version and Build Number" which is ticked by default. If left checked, Xcode will automatically set your app's version number which (rather counter-intuitively), ***will also apply to all included frameworks***. In other words, if your app version is 1.0, your framework version will be overwritten with 1.0.

Make sure you disable this option to avoid your framework version being overwritten.

You can also opt-out of this new behaviour by setting `manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber` in your export options plist.

For further details, see [this discussion on the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690647).

Comment: why `Bundle(identifier: "com.yourframework.Framework")`  always return nil? (swift 4.1)

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but just to check, did you change the identifier to the identifier of your framework?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I guess you know this doesn't work for a `Static Framework` as that is not inside the app's `Bundle` [ it is compiled into the main binary file ].

Answer (score 4):

These variables are populated in an automatically generated .c file when building from the project's `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION`. It looks like this:

```c
 extern const unsigned char FrameworkVersionString[];
 extern const double FrameworkVersionNumber;

 const unsigned char FrameworkVersionString[] __attribute__ ((used)) = "@(#)PROGRAM:Mark2SDK  PROJECT:Framework-1" "\n";
 const double FrameworkVersionNumber __attribute__ ((used)) = (double)1.;
```

The C array doesn't make it to Swift for some reason. Modifying the array definition to a pointer causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash. What you can do though is create a pointer to the array and use that. In `Framework.h`:

```c
//! Project version string for Framework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char FrameworkVersionString[];
// add this
extern const unsigned char * FrameworkVersionStringPtr;
```

Then, either by creating `Framework.c` or in another c or m file, add this:

```c
#import "Framework.h"

const unsigned char * FrameworkVersionStringPtr = FrameworkVersionString;
```

You can then use the string pointer in Swift to get the version:

```
func version() -> String? {
    let ver = String(cString: Mark2SDKVersionStringPtr)
    guard let range = ver.range(of: "-") else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(ver[range.upperBound...])
}
print(version())
// 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

for swift 4.2 it works:

```
if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.ingconti.SampleFramework") {
       if let build = bundle.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] {
           print(build)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Helper derived from ingconti

```
func fillVersionFor(for aClass: AnyClass, key: String) {
    let shortVersionStringKey = "CFBundleShortVersionString"
    let bundle = Bundle(for: aClass)
    if let build = bundle.infoDictionary?[shortVersionStringKey] as? String {
        yourDictionaryOf3rdPartyDependenciesVersions[key] = build
    }
}
```