# Is there a constant defined for CFBundleShortVersionString in iOS/MacOS framework

Tags: ios, macos, foundation

I know there is a constant for the "CFBundleVersion" plist key - defined as `kCFBundleVersionKey` in CoreFoundation's CFBundle.h header.

But is there a similar constant for "CFBundleShortVersionString" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. The supported keys are

- `kCFBundleInfoDictionaryVersionKey;`
- `kCFBundleExecutableKey;`
- `kCFBundleIdentifierKey;`
- `kCFBundleVersionKey;`
- `kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey;`
- `kCFBundleNameKey;`
- `kCFBundleLocalizationsKey;`

Comment: Interesting, yeah that's what I saw too. Do you know why only those - like maybe those are the only ones that are required for an app's bundle?

Comment: I have no idea, but you could define your own set of constants which can be useful since the type in `CFBundle` is `CFStringRef` rather than `NSString` or Swift `String`