# How to get the Framework version in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have my custom framework (*MyFramework*) which I am using in an app. I want to get the custom framework's version number which is 2.1. But if I tried it in my app by using the `FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkVersionNumber` which is given by Xcode, it's always returning 1.0. I want to get the actual version (2.1) in my app.

Comment: may be this is your bundle verson no , check properly once

Comment: see this once may be it helps you https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27862078/In-objective-C-how-to-determine-a-library-framework-version.html

Comment: Thanks karthik :) I found a way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538215/get-version-number-of-ios-universal-framework-in-client . Look at the comments given by OutOfBoundException in the answer