# How to get current version of sparkle framework used in MacOS Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, sparkle

I want to check whether I am using latest version of sparkle framework. I manually added Sparkle framework long back, now I wish to check its version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibility through code listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538215/get-version-number-of-ios-universal-framework-in-client). i.e., read info.plist inside framework. Also you can manually visit `Sparkle.framework⁩ ▸ ⁨Versions⁩ ▸ ⁨A⁩ ▸ ⁨Resources⁩⁩ ▸ ⁨Info.plist` and can check `Bundle version` property.